# Inheritance - Could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i'm newbie developer....

i really need help at now...
i just get started with Nhibernate thing at .Net...
when i learn Inheritance and try it...it makes me confusing...why i get error like this :

*Initializing[AP.Core.Domain.AccountPayable.APInvoice#API03/04/2010/001]-Could not initialize proxy - no Session.*

this is my xml :

```
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="AP.Core.Domain.AccountPayable.APAdjustment, AP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="APAdjustment">
    <id name="AdjustmentNumber" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="AdjustmentNumber" length="17" />
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="Amount" type="System.Decimal, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Amount" />
    </property>
    <property name="TransactionDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="TransactionDate" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one class="AP.Core.Domain.AccountPayable.APInvoice, AP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" lazy="proxy" name="PurchaseInvoice">
      <column name="PurchaseInvoice_id" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
    <joined-subclass name="AP.Core.Domain.AccountPayable.APCreditAdjustment, AP.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" lazy="true" table="APCreditAdjustment">
      <key>
        <column name="APAdjustment_id"  />
      </key>
    </joined-subclass>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and this is inheritance Class :

Parent Class -->

```
public class APAdjustment
        {
        #region :FIELD
        private string adjustmentNumber;
        private decimal amount;
        private DateTime transactionDate;
        private APInvoice purchaseInvoice;
```

Child Class -->

```
public class APCreditAdjustment : APAdjustment {

  public APCreditAdjustment(){
```

and this my Data access :

```
public IList<APAdjustment> GetByNameAll()
{
   ICriteria criteria = Nhibernatesession.CreateCriteria(typeof(APAdjustment));
   return criteria.List<APAdjustment>() ;
}
```

My Problem is :

1. when i load data with gridview ...it
   works...but i change the property to
   autogenerate="true" ...i missing
   "PurchaseInvoice" field...and i
   change to bind manually,and it
   works..when i edit that gridview
   ...i get this
   error...

   Initializing[AP.Core.Domain.AccountPayable.APInvoice#API03/04/2010/001]-Could
       not initialize proxy - no Session
2. so then i change my xml
   ...lazy="no-proxy" ...it still
   work...but when edit again ...i get
   error again ..and i do "Comment out
   the selected lines" to my
   association "Many-to-one"...i really
   works it..but that's not i want...

CAN ANYBODY HELP ME...??Plizz...:(

Note : I almost forget it ,i use fluent hibernate to generate to database.From fluent Hibernate ..i put *.xml file ...so i'm work to xml NHibernate...not fluent hibernate thing...:)

Comment: I wonder which sample/doc are you using to learn NH. The mapping has things that can be improved. NH uses properties, and those must be virtual because NH creates a proxy of them. I suggest you put the complete code (not just a part) and the will see.

Comment: i'm sorry...i forgot to tell you ...all my code has become virtual property ...without virtual ...my code can't runable...

this is a part of my code :

public virtual string AdjustmentNumber
{
  get { return adjustmentNumber; }
  set { adjustmentNumber = value; }
}
public virtual decimal Amount
{
 get { return amount; }
 set { amount = value; }
 }
 public virtual DateTime TransactionDate
 {
  get { return transactionDate; }
  set { transactionDate = value; }
 }
       
public virtual APInvoice PurchaseInvoice
 {
 get { return purchaseInvoice; }
 set { purchaseInvoice = value; }
 }

Comment: how is your session handling - this occurs normally if NHibernate is trying to lazy load a property and the session is gone.. so please give us more information about Nhibernatesession

Comment: I take NhibernateSessionManager from this link --> http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/8b94e3e0-3ffd-4b59-b6ce-ed4d46158a7c.aspx...and in web layer ,i put NhibernatesessionModule...to handle web session ...
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginTransaction);
            context.EndRequest += new EventHandler(CommitAndCloseSession);
        } private void BeginTransaction(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         //   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.BeginTransaction();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of your associations, put this at your code:

> not-found="ignore"

Comment: Not only a bad and questionable answer provided by chance, you didn't provide any information on what that does. Look here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726668/nhibernate-force-not-found-ignore-to-not-execute-an-extra-select

Answer (score 0):

This exception usually means that you are a trying to access a lazy-loaded property when the session is closed (I see `lazy="proxy"` in the mapping file). I suggest you to put a breakpoint before the access to "PurchaseInvoice" property and check your `Session.IsOpen` for the session your instance of APAdjustment belong.

Comment: yeah...looks like my session is null...how can I fix it??I do like this... ISession session = null; 
            ICriteria criteria = null;
            Boolean _check = NHibernateSession.IsOpen;
            try
            {
                session = NHibernateSession.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
                criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(APAdjustment));

            }
            catch (HibernateException ex)
            {

                log.Error(ex.GetBaseException());

            }
or did i something wrong in my code??

Answer (score 0):

If the session is null you're facing a totally different problem now (you couldn't obtain the previous error if your sesion were null, I believe you've changed something in your code)
Session management need a session manager and a session context class (see nHibernate doc [here](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-2-architecture/1nr4enxv3dpeq/6#2(2E)3(2E)(C2)(A0)Contextual_Sessions)) 
I suggest you to simplify a bit your design and don't introduce a session manager untile you've completely understood the implication (though a session manager it's a strongly recommended practices for many projects). Just open a new session like

```
ISession session = YouSessionFactory.OpenSession()
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(APAdjustment));
```

and go forward getting rid of the SessionManager (just for testing purpose). If you're using lazy loading, the session MUST BE OPEN when your accessing the lazy loaded property, probably your session manager don't work as you expect

Regards, Marco