# NHibernate force not-found ignore to not execute an extra select

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many, nhibernate-mapping

I'm working with a legacy database where FK's aren't always used.
For example I have an entity Person and an entity Country. A person has a Country which is mapped as a many-to-one in the Person mapping.

```
<many-to-one name="Country" class="Country" foreign-key="none" lazy="false" not-found="ignore" fetch="join" outer-join="true" column="countryid"/>
```

When person has `null` as column value (countryid) it won't perform an extra select query (because it knows that there won't be a reference in the country table), but when a person has `0` as column value NH will perform another select to check the country tabel wether the country actually doesn't exist. But because we do a left outer join, NH should already know that it doesn't exist.
Just to clarify, if a the column has a value of `1` and it is present in the country table, it will not perform an extra select.

Is there anyway to tell NHibernate not to do the extra select query?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way how to do this via configuration. Nice post how to *improve* the `not-found="ignore"` functionality:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/28/how-to-use-0-instead-of-null-for-foreign-keys.aspx

We can use some of NHibernate extension points like custom `PocoEntityTuplizer`, but there is no simple configuration, no setting...

**Some extract**:
from the link above *(read it to get more details)*. During the build process of the `Person` entity will collection `object[] values` contain also `CountryProxy`. Let's say that missing in DB is one with Id == 0 (use your own logic there as needed). This proxy will be replaced with `null` so no SELECT will be executed...

```
public class NullableTuplizer : PocoEntityTuplizer
{
    public override void SetPropertyValues(object entity, object[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (typeof (Country).IsAssignableFrom(getters[i ].ReturnType)
                && ((Country) values[i]).Id == 0) // missing id 
            {
                values[i] = null; // here change a Proxy to null
            }
        }
        base.SetPropertyValues(entity, values);
    }
...
```

Comment: NHibernate already has the select done, before he comes into this method. I've tried this, even if for example I set every `value[i] = null;` without the `if (typeof...) {` around it (so I actually set every value to null, the select still gets executed. And it also doesn't come into the GetPropertyValue first.
Also the SetPropertyValues doesn't set the proxy afaik, but the actual POCO.

Comment: Also I'm _not_ lazy loading. So I don't know if that has something to do with it.

Comment: I tried that solution and I was able to get the ID from proxy ((Country) values[i]).Id == 0) immediately, without any other select. NHibernate is able to return that value (the ID property) because it is available (loaded with Person entity in one trip to SQL). if not-null="false" on Country mapping, Nhibernate was then happy with Country instance being null. Or am I missing something? anyhow, as I said, this is workaround, the not-found="ignore" is a pain...