# Why do broken relationships cause extra selects in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

So I have a table that is loaded with a few ManyToOne joins.

If any of these joins are broken (ie. have a key reference where the joined table does not contain that key) an exception gets thrown unless you set the property 'NotFoundMode.Ignore'.

I've noticed that when there are mismatches, I get a whole lot of extra selects being sent to the database.

The main select is done once, then for each of the mismatches there is an extra select sent out.

I've confirmed this by fixing the references (all the extra selects disappear) and then rebreaking the references (all the selects reappear).

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The Ignore setting is very fragile. I would say, that for sure you won't find some nice solution to this (except of fixing the DB, which **I strongly suggest**). Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729851/1679310 and also this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18652713/1679310

Comment: Fixing the database isn't very easy, the join is on a string field, and empty strings are the issue. Our database has a legacy database attached which forces empty strings in certain fields (gross)

Comment: I understand that... that is why we do have "ignore" setting. But as I tried expalain, it is legacy feature. We cannot expect to be the top of the product, if you know what I mean

Comment: Good point. You've basically answered the question. Could you paraphrase the link you posted as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As quickly discussed in the comments above: The setting `NotFoundMode.Ignore` is really mostly for legacy stuff.

It give us the option how to handle inconsistent `foreign-keys` in DB. If we cannot fix the underlying tables, we at least can use the `not-found="ignore"` setting.

Please see these Q&A for some more information, about down side of that setting. It should give the answer, why are "repeated selects" of the "not existing" values issued:

- [NHibernate force not-found ignore to not execute an extra select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726668/)
- [NHibernate Prevent Lazy Loading of unmatched reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18652419/)